# Duplicated Save and Cancel buttons in Settings View

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I am trying to define a settings view for a custom module.

I have followed both the official documentation and a blog which helps you to adapt the code to Odoo 10:

http://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/py/res.config.settings.html
http://ludwiktrammer.github.io/odoo/custom-settings-odoo.html

Currently this is my code to display the form:

```
    <record id="mymodule_configuration_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">TEST Settings</field>
        <field name="model">mymodule_settings</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form class="oe_form_configuration">
                <header>
                    <button string="Save" type="object"
                        name="execute" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button string="Cancel" type="object"
                        name="cancel" class="oe_link"/>
                </header>
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <label for="color"/>
                        <field name="color"/>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

And this is the code for the menus:

```
    <menuitem id="mymodule_menu"
              name="Custom Saleorder"
              parent="base.menu_custom" />

    <act_window id="mymodule_settings_action"
                name="Custom Saleorder Settings Action"
                res_model="mymodule_settings"
                view_mode="form" />
    <menuitem id="mymodule_settings_menu"
              name="Settings"
              action="mymodule_settings_action"
              parent="mymodule_menu" />
```

But while doing this I find that I have duplicated the buttons, how do I remove the above ones?

[image]

I think that the fact that I am dealing with a model which inherits res.config.settings is relevant.

Comment: You dont need to add Save and cancel button. Odoo will append itself. Just remove those buttons from header section. and Try again.

Comment: I did that in first place, but buttons added by default by Odoo are not saving/updating ir_config_param table.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the buttons you have added, these buttons are automatically created and shown by Odoo (depending on the user's rights).

When you click Save, any method that starts with `set_` is invoked, so do **create a method for example named `def set_settings`** and that method will be automatically invoked (assuming your settings model inherits from `res.config.settings`) in that method save the your settings.

Take a look at the docstring of `odoo/addons/base/res/res_config.py`